# Jackson ignores important property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two entity classes, praum and praumgruppe.
This classes are hibernate and java jackson mapper.

I use spring / jersey for development in mvc.

In the class praum is use the class praumgruppe. Class praumgruppe also returns a list of praum objects.

Code from class praumgruppe

```
package de.decon.flaeche.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonManagedReference;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

import de.decon.catalogs.model.DeconKatEintragModel;
import de.decon.catalogs.model.KatKostenstelleModel;
import de.decon.flaeche.model.interfaces.PraumgruppeModelInterface;

@Entity
@Table(name = "p_raumgruppe")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PraumgruppeModel implements PraumgruppeModelInterface {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "praumgruppe", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = PraumModel.class)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    private List<PraumModel> listPraum = new ArrayList<PraumModel>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<PraumModel> getListPraum() {
        return listPraum;
    }

    public void setListPraum(List<PraumModel> listPraum) {
        this.listPraum = listPraum;
    }
}
```

Code from class praum

```
package de.decon.flaeche.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

import de.decon.catalogs.model.DeconKatEintragModel;
import de.decon.flaeche.model.interfaces.PraumModelInterface;

@Entity
@Table(name = "p_raum")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PraumModel implements PraumModelInterface {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PraumgruppeModel.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_praumgruppe")
    private PraumgruppeModel praumgruppe;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PraumModel.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_p_raum")
    private PraumModel parent;

    /**
     * Getter und Setter
     */
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonProperty("praumgruppe")
    @JsonIgnore(false)
    public PraumgruppeModel getPraumgruppe() {
        return praumgruppe;
    }

    public void setPraumgruppe(PraumgruppeModel praumgruppe) {
        this.praumgruppe = praumgruppe;
    }

    @JsonProperty("parent")
    public PraumModel getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(PraumModel parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Code from a method of the PraumController

```
@Path("/load/{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public Response loadPraum(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Long praumId = Long.parseLong(id);
        PraumModelInterface praum = praumService.getObjectById(praumId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(praum).build();
    }
```

In the response always missing the property praumgruppe.

```
{
    "name": "test 15.2.3.1.1.3.1",
    "parent": {
        "name": "test 15.2.3.1.1.3",
        "parent": null,
        "id": 30088,
        "nr": "3",
        "notiz": null,
        "fertigstellung": null,
        "schwachstrom": null,
        "nrArchitekt": null,
        "bodenFlaeche": 0,
        "deckeFlaeche": 0,
        "wandFlaeche": 0,
        "vollreinigung": null,
        "sichtreinigung": null,
        "katDin2771": null,
        "katDin2772": null,
        "katDin2773": null,
        "katDin130801": null,
        "katDin130802": null,
        "katDin130803": null,
        "katRaumBoden": null,
        "katRaumDecke": null,
        "katRaumWand": null,
        "katRaumKriteriumBoden": null,
        "katRaumKriteriumDecke": null,
        "katRaumKriteriumWand": null,
        "bgf": 0,
        "cadId": null,
        "ngf": 0,
        "umfang": 0,
        "hud": 0,
        "hrd": 0,
        "sanitaer": null,
        "heizung": null,
        "lueftung": null,
        "elektro": null
    },
    "id": 30087,
    "nr": "1",
    "notiz": null,
    "fertigstellung": null,
    "schwachstrom": null,
    "nrArchitekt": null,
    "bodenFlaeche": 0,
    "deckeFlaeche": 0,
    "wandFlaeche": 0,
    "vollreinigung": null,
    "sichtreinigung": null,
    "katDin2771": null,
    "katDin2772": null,
    "katDin2773": null,
    "katDin130801": null,
    "katDin130802": null,
    "katDin130803": null,
    "katRaumBoden": null,
    "katRaumDecke": null,
    "katRaumWand": null,
    "katRaumKriteriumBoden": null,
    "katRaumKriteriumDecke": null,
    "katRaumKriteriumWand": null,
    "bgf": 0,
    "cadId": null,
    "ngf": 0,
    "umfang": 0,
    "hud": 0,
    "hrd": 0,
    "sanitaer": null,
    "heizung": null,
    "lueftung": null,
    "elektro": null
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try putting the jackson annotations on getters.

Comment: You've posted quite a bit of code here. Maybe you could simplify it? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The code is is reduced to the bare minimum and relevant for the problem,